# Exporting RDLC to .docx file

Tags: c#, rdlc

I need the C# code to export the rdlc file to .docx. I have tried out the following code.But it does not work. Please help me with proper code.Thanks in advance

```
RvQpTemplate.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { 
             regulation, ExamName, SubjectName, SubjectCode,common });
var report = new LocalReport();
report.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

RvQpTemplate.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource());
RvQpTemplate.DataBind();

Byte[] mybytes = RvQpTemplate.LocalReport.Render("WORD", null,
                                    out extension, out encoding,
                                    out mimeType, out streams, out warnings);
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = contentType;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="test.docx");
Response.BinaryWrite(mybytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

Comment: `rdlc` is a report definition. It makes no sense to export it to a document. Are you asking how to render a report as a Word document? What is the problem? Do you get an exception, no result, a mangled document?

Comment: 'does not work' is not a technical description to work on to solve an issue...

Comment: you cannot simply create .docx files and expect them to open in Word.. you need to explicitly create them./.. do you need this ??

Answer (score 4):

Use WORDOPENXML instead of WORD when you render the report. Also, this was discussed here:
[How do I export directly to a word document in report viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184042/how-do-i-export-directly-to-a-word-document-in-report-viewer)

Answer (score 0):

```
public FileResult File(string id, string expedicion, string nombre, string historia)
    {                                    
        ReportViewer ReportViewer1 = new ReportViewer();
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = 
        Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/Plantilla2.rdlc");

        ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
        ReportParameter ID = new ReportParameter("ID", id);
        ReportParameter EXP = new ReportParameter("Exp", expedicion);
        ReportParameter Nombre = new ReportParameter("Nombre", nombre);
        ReportParameter Historia = new ReportParameter("Historia", historia);
        ReportParameter Sede = new ReportParameter("Sede", usuario.idnom);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(ID);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(EXP);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Nombre);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Historia);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Sede);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();


        byte[] streamBytes = null;
        string mimeType = "";
        string encoding = "";
        string filenameExtension = "";
        string[] streamids = null;
        Warning[] warnings = null;

        streamBytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("WORD", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);
        return File(streamBytes, mimeType, "Report1.doc");
    }
```